# What does the following snippet do with num?

Tags: javascript

I read some other's code, there is some piece of code below. I am wondering What does the method do with num?

```
 formatNumber: function (num, digit) {
            var pow = Math.pow(10, digit || 5);
            return Math.round(num * pow) / pow;
    }
```

BTW when I running
formatNum(11.267898, 5), it gave me 11.2679, is this OK?

Comment: multiplies it by pow, rounds it, then divides by pow

Comment: why don't you run it in console

Comment: seriously though, it's almost the same as `return parseFloat(num.toFixed(digit || 5))`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the function returns the number with certain precision. The precision is `digit`, which is 5 if not provided.

The return part essentially brings that many values (equal to `digit`) decimal right to left and then discard the rest and finally divides again to get the original value reduces to precision of `digit`.

Regarding BTW edit -

The value obtained is correct. See details below

When you call `formatNum(11.267898, 5)`, you're asking the number to round to 5 digit precision and your number has 6 digit precision - `precision` is digits after the dot.

Now when you call `num * pow` the number becomes `1126789.8` and when you round this number, it rounds to closest integer which is `11.26790`. Finally when you divide it by `pow` (`100000`), the number becomes 11.2679, discarding last 0 as trailing Zero in precision is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

That is a really poor piece of code.

First, the naming conventions don't match what the code does at all.

- The function name `formatNumber()` suggests that it *formats* a number. In other words, it ought to produce a *string representation* of a number, formatted in some way. But the function doesn't do this, it returns another number. That makes no sense. Numbers don't have a format, they are just numbers.
- The parameter name `digit` sounds like it would contain a single digit. But it doesn't. It contains a *count* of digits that you want to round the number to. When you name things, singular and plural matter!

It gets worse.

As you found, the function doesn't even work. In your example, `formatNum(11.267898,5)` returns the number `11.2679`. Why did it give you four digits when you asked for five? The result you were expecting was `11.26790`, wasn't it? Well, of course that is identical to `11.2679`, if we're talking about numbers. But what good does that do you when you wanted five digits?

Or to take a ridiculously simple example: `formatNumber(1,2)`. You might expect that to produce `1.00`, but it produces `1`. Of course that is really the same value, but not formatted the way you want.

Now we go from the ridiculous to the sublime.

JavaScript has always had a built-in function that does *exactly* what we would expect `formatNumber()` to do: `number.toFixed(digits)`. This does proper rounding and always returns the number of digits after the decimal point that you ask for. And of course, to be able to do that, it returns a string, not a number.

If we try these examples using `.toFixed()` they work as expected:

`(11.267898).toFixed(5)` returns the string `"11.26790"`.

`(1).toFixed(2)` returns `"1.00"`.

And so on, for just about anything you can throw at it. (It gives up on numbers with magnitude too large and uses exponential notation instead.)

Note that the parentheses around the first number in those examples are just needed to avoid a syntax error; in most cases you'd be using a variable and they would not be required, e.g.

`myNumber.toFixed(2)`

To summarize, not only does `formatNumber()` not do what it says and not anything useful, it was never needed in the first place!